# Query GraphQL with a list of values

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

Trying to query a list of Employee objects by providing a list of `emp_codes` but feeling like I am missing something in my following GraphQL query.

Also tried looking into this `emp_code__in=emp_codes` without luck.

I appreciate your insights since I am fairly new to GraphQL

```
emp_codes_list = ['1', '2', '3']
# Expecting to return: [{empCode: '1', firstName: 'J', lastName: S'}, {empCode: '2', firstName: 'T', lastName: S'}, {empCode: '3', firstName: 'A', lastName: B'}]

    query() = f"""
      {{
        profileEmpCode(empCode:"{emp_codes_list}") {{
          ... on Employeelist {{
            Employeelist {{
              firstName
              lastName
              empCode
            }}
          }}
          ... on AuthInfoField {{
            message
          }}
        }}
      }}
    """
```

Comment: graphql abusing - input/params should be passed by variables, not by query string manipulations

Answer (score 1):

`"{emp_codes_list}"` passes a string but not a list to the GraphQL server.

```
import json
emp_codes_list = json.dumps(['1', '2', '3'])
# Expecting to return: [{empCode: '1', firstName: 'J', lastName: S'}, {empCode: '2', firstName: 'T', lastName: S'}, {empCode: '3', firstName: 'A', lastName: B'}]

query() = f"""
  {{
    profileEmpCode(empCode:{emp_codes_list}) {{
      ... on Employeelist {{
        Employeelist {{
          firstName
          lastName
          empCode
        }}
      }}
      ... on AuthInfoField {{
        message
      }}
    }}
  }}
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to viewers.

You can using [graphql-query](https://denisart.github.io/graphql-query/) package as best way for GraphQL query string generation in python:

```py
from graphql_query import Argument, InlineFragment, Field, Operation, Query

arg_emp_code = Argument(name="empCode", value=['"1"', '"2"', '"3"'])

profile_emp_code = Query(
    name="profileEmpCode",
    arguments=[arg_emp_code],
    fields=[
        InlineFragment(
            type="Employeelist",
            fields=[
                Field(name="Employeelist", fields=["firstName", "lastName", "empCode"])
            ]
        ),
        InlineFragment(type="AuthInfoField", fields=["message"]),
    ]
)
operation = Operation(type="query", queries=[profile_emp_code])

print(operation.render())
"""
query {
  profileEmpCode(
    empCode: ["1", "2", "3"]
  ) {
    ... on Employeelist {
      Employeelist {
        firstName
        lastName
        empCode
      }
    }
    ... on AuthInfoField {
      message
    }
  }
}
"""
```